# ASP MVC - Is there a way to dynamically create an object in my view based on my model and map it to my input fields? (to be sent via Ajax)

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

My model:

```
public class MyDerived: Base
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

My controller's Action Method:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Add(MyDerived obj)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Items.Add(obj);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home", new { area = "" });
    }

    return View(phone);
}
```

My view (rendered as partial view):

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstName, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstName)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName)
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LastName, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LastName)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LastName)
    </div>
</div>
```

My Ajax:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#but').on("click", function () {
        var theData = {
            FirstName: $('#FirstName').val(),
            LastName: $('#LastName').val()
            }

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Home/Add",
            data: theData,
            success: function (response, status, xhr) {
                $('#partialPlaceHolder').html("ok");
            },
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                $('#partialPlaceHolder').html("not working");
            }
        })
    })
})
```

So my question regards my 'theData' object... I created this manually based on what my model expect but if my model happens to change this will have to be manually changed too. It looks like it wouldn't be good practice but I don't know how to do it otherwise. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would try to serialize all inputs in your form with [jQuery.serialize](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/) method.

For this you would need to wrap all your fields with form tag like this:

```
<form id="userForm">
  //here your divs with fields
</form>
```

and then in your script you would need to just call serialize on your form object like this:

```
var theData = $("#userForm").serialize();
```

Comment: This was it but instead of the basic HTML form I used 

@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "userForm" })) in my view. That worked well.